# Why does Inosuke have a girly face?

Tags: demon-slayer

Inosuke of *Kimetsu no Yaiba* has a distinctive girly face for which he wears a boar mask to hide his face and avoid embarrassment. My question is: "why does he has a girly face in the first place?" He has a clear male voice and a male body, so why does he have a girl's face?

Comment: Why not? There are boys like that in real life here in Japan and everywhere else. The opposite is also true - girls with boyish faces.

Comment: Inosuke is not the first nor the last anime character you'll encounter with a feminine-like face despite being biologically male.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no explanation in the manga about his face being girly. We saw his mother and her face is beautiful, but we never see his father. In anime and manga, you can see lots of girly-faced characters.

Basically, the mangaka wanted to make an interesting character, that's all. After some time, you get used to his face and it does look less girly. I started to notice again that his face looked girly after I saw your post.